# Work requires answering dozens of drop down questions, can I automate answering them?

Tags: automated-testing, java, browser-automation, javascript, test-strategy

If I just knew a script could answer the questions for me, I would learn from scratch in order to teach myself how to create the script to answer the questions.

I personally do not know who to ask to determine if this would even be possible.  This has resulted in my presence here, among the people I believe may know.

Background:

- `Website` is `Java` based according to the IT department (also by inspecting the website)
- Every order requires the answers to a set of `drop down` questions

I will give as much information as I possibly can in order to assist those, who are attempting to help me.

`Edit: 12/13/2018`

Over this time away from this question I learned, that what I needed to do can be accomplished through a programming language like `Java` or `Python` in conjunction with `Selenium`.

I have also found that by using the `Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey` browser `Extension` and `JavaScript` has allowed for a combination of automation of form filling with single clicks as well as increased functionality on the `web API`, that I use for work.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Any website automation is possible using selenium.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like I have some new stuff to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to web automation, try one of the free record & replay tools to get started. These are easier to use than "pure" Selenium/Webdriver:

- [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)
- [Kantu Web Automation](https://a9t9.com/kantu/web-automation#formfilling)
- [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/)

Comment: Thank you Bobby, these are exactly what I was looking for and you may have prevented a future stress heart attack.

Answer (score 0):

*(I don't have enough rep so I'm posting this as a top level answer rather than a comment. Please delete it if it violates any ToS.)*

If you don't have an automation background, you could use [my tool](http://kheera.in/) to achieve this. It provides a collection of verbs to support automation operations like

- open a URL
- click on web elements
- put text
- clear text fields etc.

I'd be happy to work with you to write your first automated scripts if you want which you can then replicate for further use. Since I only just launched it, documentation is a little spotty but I believe it can easily achieve what you wish to do.

Comment: Thank you very much Sai, I will look into your tool and I may be in contact about a whole different tool.